# Percentage within category

Tags: r

I have a data-frame like this (except with many more rows and sizes, say):

```
   size amount
1   big      1
2   big      9
3 small      3
4 small      1
```

and I would like to get a data frame like this, where amountPct is amount divided by the sum of amounts with the same size.

```
   size amountPct
1   big      0.10
2   big      0.90
3 small      0.75
4 small      0.25
```

I can do this by reshaping the data frame, dividing through by the sum for each size, and then reshaping it back to the original shape, but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ave` and `prop.table`.

```
> transform(dat, amountPct = ave(amount, size, FUN = prop.table))

   size amount amountPct
1   big      1      0.10
2   big      9      0.90
3 small      3      0.75
4 small      1      0.25
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: I like this approach but for the life of me I can't understand what `prop.table` does... Is there a layman's explanation?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten Basically, `prop.table` calculates the relative value of a value in a vector compared to the sum of all values in this vector. E.g., `x / sum(x)`. (The actual function is a bit more complicated but that's the way it works.)

Answer (score 2):

Your data is already in *long* format. You don't have to *melt* here. You just have to group by the `size` column. Here's a solution using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, list(amountPct = amount/sum(amount)), by=size]

#     size amountPct
# 1:   big      0.10
# 2:   big      0.90
# 3: small      0.75
# 4: small      0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
library(plyr)
ddply(d, .(size), function(x) {
  x$amount <- x$amount / sum(x$amount, na.rm=T)
  x
})

   size amount
1   big   0.10
2   big   0.90
3 small   0.75
4 small   0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use '[***dplyr***](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/)' a new package (author: Hadley Wickham ) which provides a blazingly fast set of tools for efficiently manipulating datasets.

```
require(dplyr)

mutate(group_by(df,size),am_pcnt = amount/sum(amount))

   size amount am_pcnt
1   big      1    0.10
2   big      9    0.90
3 small      3    0.75
4 small      1    0.25
```