# Pandas: Percentage within Category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame like this (except with many more rows and sizes, say):

```
   size amount
1   big      1
2   big      9
3 small      3
4 small      1
```

and I would like to get a data frame like this, where amountPct is amount divided by the sum of amounts with the same size.

```
   size amountPct
1   big      0.10
2   big      0.90
3 small      0.75
4 small      0.25
```

I can do this by reshaping the data frame, dividing through by the sum for each size, and then reshaping it back to the original shape, but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

PS: I asked the same question for R but now I would like the answer for Pandas!

Comment: Here was the R version of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195651/percentage-within-category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'size':['big', 'big', 'small', 'small'], 'amount':[1, 9, 3, 1]})
df['pct'] = df.groupby('size')['amount'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(float)/x.sum())
```

Comment: in 0.13.1, this will be included via rank (will be faster too): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5978

Comment: So this works, thanks, but I'm having trouble understanding why... Could you please explain? In the `lambda`, what is `x` ?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten the x in this case is the column 'amount'

Comment: @EdChum thanks! So `apply` gets called once for the column or once per element? `x.astype(float)` is the whole column or just one element? and `x.sum()` is the group by group sum? How do these rules work? :)

Comment: @nicolaskruchten in this case it will be called once per element but the implmentation is optimised in cython (I think) so it is faster than a hand written for loop